# Compute/dominate $\int_s^t \gamma(\tau) d\tau$ for large $t$

Tags: integration, analysis, inequality

Let the dispersion map $\gamma$ is 1-periodic,  i.e.  $\gamma(t+1)=\gamma (t)$ and piecewise constant:
\begin{eqnarray}
\gamma(t)=
\begin{cases} \gamma_+ \quad  0<t\leq t_+\\
-\gamma_ {- } \quad  t_+ <t \leq 1
\end{cases}
\end{eqnarray}
where $\gamma_{\pm}$ are some positive  constants and $t_+ \in (0,1).$ We  denote by
$$\Gamma (t,s)=\int_s^t \gamma(\tau) d\tau $$

> Question:
> Can we show that
> $|\Gamma (t, t_0)| \geq C |t|$ for $t \geq t_0$  is sufficiently large?

Motivation: This function appeared in dispersion managed nonlinear Schrodinger equation.

Comment: The periodicity coupled with negative/positive aspects means it is highly relevant what the relative sizes of $\gamma_+,\gamma_-$ are. If the two are equal, this integral oscillates and no asymptotic behaviour can be found

Comment: @FShrike: Thanks. Please can you elaborate bit more?

Answer (score 1):

I should have also said, what the relative sizes of ... *and* how large $t_+$ is. We need more detail. E.g. Let $t_+=1/2$ and $\gamma_+=1=\gamma_-$. Then $\Gamma(x,0)=x$, for $0\le x\le1/2$: $\Gamma(x,0)=1/2-(x-1/2)=1-x$ for $1/2\le x\le1$, with $\Gamma(1,0)=1=\Gamma(0,0)$. It is clear that $\Gamma(n,0)=0$ for integer $n$ yet $\Gamma(n+1/2,0)=1/2$ for integer $n$. In short, the integral oscillates and no satisfactory asymptotic can be found.

But if $t_+=0.9$, $\gamma_+=10=\gamma_-$, $\Gamma(0,0)=0,\Gamma(1,0)=8;\Gamma(2,0)=16,...\Gamma(n,0)=8n$ which has a completely different asymptotic behaviour.

These two quick identities are important.

> $$\begin{align}\tag{1}\Gamma(x,0)&=\Gamma(\lfloor x\rfloor,0)+\Gamma(\{x\},0)\\\tag{2}\Gamma(n,0)&=n\cdot\Gamma(1,0),&n\in\Bbb N\end{align}$$

The key value is $\lambda=\Gamma(1,0)$.

If this is zero, then that means $t_+\gamma_+=(1-t_+)\gamma_-$ and $\Gamma(x,0)=\Gamma(\lfloor x\rfloor,0)+\Gamma(\{x\},0)=\Gamma(\{x\},0)$, which periodically increases on $0\le\{x\}\le t_+$ and then decreases to zero on $t_+\le\{x\}\le1$.

If $\Gamma(1,0)>0$, then that means $t_+\gamma_+>(1-t_+)\gamma_-$. Using $(1)$ and $(2)$ together, $\Gamma(x,0)=\lambda\cdot\lfloor x\rfloor+\Gamma(\{x\},0)$. The latter term is periodically increasing, and then decreasing to some positive value ($\lambda$) whereas the former term increases with $\lfloor x\rfloor$. Then: $$\Gamma(x,0)\sim\lambda x$$As an asymptotic relation which is very quickly accurate. If you want a bound, $|\Gamma(x,0)|=\Gamma(x,0)\ge\lambda\lfloor x\rfloor$ follows.

If $\lambda<0$ then $t_+\gamma_+<(1-t_+)\gamma_-$. You get the same behaviour as above, with the same proof, except $\Gamma(\{x\},0)$ periodically decreases below zero and $\Gamma(x,0)$ decreases with $\lfloor x\rfloor$.

Be warned that the periodic $\Gamma(\{x\},0)$ term might spike to be much larger / lower than $\lambda$. You’d need explicit bounds on $\gamma_{+/-}$ to say any more.